# Hibernate Mapping - Joining two tables with an association table - But with a twist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, mapping, entity

I have the following entities... `Customer`, `Card` and `Address`

Customer:

```
 {
     private String cust_id; // Primary key
     .....

     @OneToOne
     Address address; // I want to load address of the customer. 
                      // Can change the association to @OneToMany, if needed
 }
```

Card:

```
 {
    private String card_id; // Primary Key
    private String cust_id; // Foreign Key to Customer.cust_id
    ....
 }
```

Address:

```
 {
    private String card_id; // Foreign key to card.card_id
    private String address1;
    .....
 }
```

When I load customers I want to load Addresses with association table `Card`. But the tricky part is `Address` does not have a primary key. It only has a Foreign key.

Comment: Have you looked at [Hibernate's support for composite keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch25.html#example-mappings-composite-key-manytomany)? Unfortunately the example is XML/HBM and it appears that you're using annotations, but it should be fairly easy to adapt.

Comment: I am searching for an example with annotation. Let me check it.

Comment: Do you have a DB schema in mind? Does a customer have multiple cards? Does a customer have multiple addresses (one per card)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the annotation @JoinTable after the @OneToOne to point the card's table, so you won't need an entity for card, but if the card's table isn't just a relational table, you could map card in User as @OneToOne and have a @Transient 'getAddress()' method that returns 'this.card.getAddress()', but on card's entity you must map the relation between Address and Card(@OneToOne(mappedBy='card_id')), and in Address you could map card_id as @Id.

**First Alternative**

Customer:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinTable(name="card", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="cust_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="card_id"))
private Address address;
```

**Second alternative**

Customer:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="cust_id")
private Card card;

...
@Transient
public Address getAddress(){
 return this.card == null ? null : this.card.getAddress();
}
```

Card:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="card_id")
private Address address;
```

Address:

```
@Id
private String card_id;
```

In the Second case Card has a Embedded pk which is formed by two fks(Customer and Address)

Card:

```
@EmbeddedId
private CustomerAddressPK id;
```

CustomerAddressPK

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerAddressPK(){

  private String cust_id;
  private String card_id;
}
```

Comment: Does the first example work? Currently, thats what I have. But I am not sure if it works. Because Card does not have a primary key. It has a foreign key.

Comment: In the first example card doesn't need a pk, because it's just a relational table, the 'card_id' should be named 'address_id' because it really represents an Address not a Card itself.

Comment: I am sorry. I mistyped. Its actually Address that does not have PK. Card does. Card.card_id (PK) -> Address.card_id (FK). Does it still work?

Comment: changing the field name makes sense. You are right. But I am stuck with it as is.

Comment: The first example should work even so, because it's making a join with card table on cust_id and then another join with address on card_id. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne

Comment: the first one didn't work. It throws the error. `A Foreign key referring Address from Customer has the wrong number of column. should be 2`. Not sure what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping between `Customer` and `Address` can be made by using the concept of [Dependent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-dependentobjects).

Look at the documentation, you will find similar example where there is a mapping between `Person` entity with dependent object called `Name`.

Comment: It doesn't cut it. Its like one table shared with two entities in parts. For ex, Customer and Address fields are in same table, but with different entities, if I got it right. Can you show an example if this is the solution?