# Hibernate many-to-one key with foreign key name

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys

Using **Hibernate 3.2.3** GA with **hbm.xml** files.

Having such a **many-to-one** key

```
<key-many-to-one name="attachment" column="attachmentId"
                     class="com.attachment.Attachment"/>
```

hibernate will auto-generate a **FK** on the table with some random ID 
(like FKD40DC872B67B3502).

How can I set the name of the respective FK with my own cutomer FK_ID name  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please , see

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414385/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-on-foreign-key)

```
<one-to-one name="product" foreign-key="productId" 
           cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" />
```

Override the hbm.xml and try to remab or execute , it will update them on run time